# How did Harry get back to The Adjustment Bureau after giving his hat away?

Tags: the-adjustment-bureau

In The Adjustment Bureau, Harry helps Congressman Norris get to Elise's marriage ceremony before she can go through it with the use of the special doors.  In order to use the doors, you have to have a special hat like the agents.  Harry gives Norris his to enable him to use them; how does Harry get back to the bureau?

Comment: And someone voted the question down- if you did so, can you explain why?

Comment: Perhaps they, like I, initially believed this to be about Harry Potter, having failed to check the tags.

Comment: I don't know how he got it, but having just re-watched it, I notice that Harry is carrying ANOTHER hat when he is called to the chairman's office slightly later.  Possibly they can 'draw' them from supply at will or some such.

Comment: @KWH - put that into an answer, and I'd vote it up...

Comment: @K-H-W - I realized I tagged you wrong.  I think your comment could easily be a good answer.  If you want to make it so, I'll accept it at this point, otherwise, I'll just answer with your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Converted from a very old comment]* 
I don't know how he got it, but having just re-watched it, I notice that Harry is carrying ANOTHER hat when he is called to the chairman's office slightly later. Possibly they can 'draw' them from supply at will or some such.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Harry opened the bureau's door connecting with the tunnels and left it slightly open, gave Norris the hat and quickly returned to the bureau.

It's posible but not so significant as to be included in the story.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple agents followed their every move and tried to stop them on their chase, including the higher powers. It's not unfeasible that the higher powers, upon realizing that the paths were going to merge and change, then allowed Harry to continue with his mission thinking that he was incognito, but actually just operating according to a larger destiny picture. They may also have sent out a rescue, or they had a fallback "emergency entrance" in case one of the agents lost their hat in daily operations.

Comment: Eh, what? How did this answer the question?